# Change a Registry Value, then Run an Application, by Using a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, regedit, dword

I want to change a registry value (a REG_DWORD), then run an application, by using a batch file, that is located in the same folder as the application.
I tried the lines below, but that does not work:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\A User Name\An Application Name" /v A value name_h3981298716 /d "99" /t REG_DWORD /f

START %~dp0AnApplicationName.exe
```

The "START ..." will work without the "reg add ..." code. The batch file can run an application, but it cannot change a registry value of REG_DWORD type.

How to do the sequence below correctly with a batch file?

1. First, change a registry value of REG_DWORD type.
2. Then run an application.

Comment: Because there is something wrong. Please be more specific!

Comment: Try surrounding `%~dp0AnApplicationName.exe` with double quotes. Whenever a batch file "does not work" place as many useful `echo`es in there and start it using a command prompt. With that you can check at what point the file failed.

Comment: The "START ..." will work without the "reg add ..." code. The batch file can run an application, but it cannot change a registry value of REG_DWORD type.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg add "HKCU\A User Name\An Application Name" /v "A value name_h3981298716" /d "99" /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Note that if a value name contains a space then it should be surrounded with double quotes. Keep doing that even if a value name does not contain any space.

Example, with another key name:

```
==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Test Key" /t reg_dword

End of search: 0 match(es) found.

==> reg add "HKCU\Software\Test Key" /v A value name_h3981298716 /d "99" /t REG_DWORD /f
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.

==> reg add "HKCU\Software\Test Key" /v "A value name_h3981298716" /d "99" /t REG_DWORD /f
The operation completed successfully.

==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Test Key" /t reg_dword

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test Key
    A value name_h3981298716    REG_DWORD    0x63

End of search: 1 match(es) found.
```

Comment: I have surrounded the value name with double quotes, then run the batch file, but the value still does not change.

Comment: @Bayu If the value does not change then you should get an error message. Add a `pause` command immediately below `reg add …` to see the result.  Check success using `reg query …` in the  same way I did in my example.

Comment: There was a message after I added "pause" below the "reg add ...":

Comment: The message is : "The operation completed successfully". But the value still does not change in the Registry Editor...

Comment: In an open registry editor, you need `F5` refresh (seen also in the `View` menu) to see changes made from another process…

Comment: Yup, it is still the same. The value doesn't change. Really strange

Comment: Impossible… Double check both key path and value name.